# How do I separate Strings with an apostrophe in them in Java?

Tags: java, string, split, delimiter

I'm trying to separate the line "That thereby beauty’s rose might never die," into individual words and my code works - except for the apostrophe. "beauty's" is still returned as "beauty's" instead of "beauty" and "s".

This is what I'm trying:

```
String line = "That thereby beauty’s rose might never die,";
String[] words = line.split("[' ,]");
```

I don't really understand adding multiple delimiters in Java but this seems to work for everything but apostrophes. Can someone please help me out and tell me what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a close look at `line`'s apostrophe and at your split apostrophe. They're different characters. `’` != `'`. You'll most likely want to convert the first one to the second one.

Some code for you to ponder:

```
String line = "That thereby beauty’s rose might never die,";
String[] words = line.split("[' ,]");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));

line = "That thereby beauty's rose might never die,";
words = line.split("[' ,]");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
```

Output:

```
[That, thereby, beauty’s, rose, might, never, die]
[That, thereby, beauty, s, rose, might, never, die]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was really helpful - can't believe I made such a rookie mistake

Comment: @user11610667 Please consider marking this answer as accepted so I can get my reputation! *laughs*

Answer (score 0):

replace `'` with `’`:

`String[] words = line.split("[’ ,]");`